# Make Public color and bind it in the Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create Color in the next way:

```
 public Color DynamicTextColor 
    {
        get
        {
            return color;
        }

        set
        {
           if(colorMode == "Dark")
            {
                value = Color.White;
            }
            else if (colorMode == "Light")
            {
                value = Color.Black;
            }

            color = value;
        }
    }
```

And Bind it in the XAML

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="labelTable" TextColor="{Binding DynamicTextColor}">
```

But color doesn't change....

Traditional way `TextColor="White"` doesn't situatable for me because I want to do `DynamicTextColor` dynamic. How can I do that?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` delegate in the parent class and call `PropertyChanged` event when your color changes.

Comment: How can I do that? Understand me right, I am new in C#.

Comment: I’ll possibly add the code later, but right now I am on the mobile phone and really can’t do that, really sorry.